# stackvm: qemu on localhost:5900 died

Tags: qemu

I am trying to run [StackVM](http://stackvm.com/). I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS in a VirtualBox. I have installed all the prerequisites for running StackVM as listed [here](http://github.com/pkrumins/stackvm/blob/master//INSTALL). AQemu and other qemu packages are also installed.

I have added one simple linux image (linux-0.2.img) which is available on qemu's [site](http://wiki.qemu.org/Download)

When I open stackvm in a browser and try to run the added simple linux image I get the following error on the terminal and nothing happens on the browser.

```
firing up qemu on localhost:5900
{ user: { name: 'foo' }
, disk: { name: 'simple linux' }
, file: 'linux-0.2.img'
, engine: 'qemu'
}
qemu on localhost:5900 died
```

Can anyone help me to get it running.